# How to use mvn deploy:file dynamically?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, nexus, bamboo

I have a bit weird use-case, where I need to modify an existing package. Basically download it, unzip, swap some files, make some adjustments and then deploy it as special artifact in our Nexus artifactory.

I created a Maven project, where I basically put everything together and then want to deploy my created jar (The maven project itself is just the sceleton for putting everything together).

Using deploy:deploy-file this is quite easy. Though I want to integrate this in our Bamboo CI and create a build pipeline. But this won't work.

When I configure it in the pom, and use mvn clean deploy in our build-pipeline I have access problems to our Nexus artifactory:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>deploy-jar</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy-file</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/my-customized.jar</file>
          <groupId>com.test.project</groupId>
          <artifactId>my-customized-service</artifactId>
          <version>${revision}${changelist}</version>
          <repositoryId>${targetrepositoryid}</repositoryId>
          <url>${targeturl}</url>
          <packaging>jar</packaging>
          <generatePom>false</generatePom>
        </configuration>
      </execution></plugin>
```

So I noticed when calling mvn clean deploy:deploy-file directly with CI pipline it works. However I can't give dynamic values. For example:

```
clean install deploy:deploy-file -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...
```

The version should be taken from the pom.xml of the Maven project. I don't want to manually change it everytime a new version is made. So I don't really know how to make it dynamic.

Comment: The question which is coming up if I read this: `I need to modify an existing package. ` ?? Why do you need to?

Comment: @khmarbaise I just need to. The open source company, which we are a partner hasn't yet given us an extension mechanism, yet, they are working on it. So long we need to find a different way to customize a few files. I could go into detail, but yes we need to do it like this for now.